# Como chamar uma script de c# dentro de uma script de python

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Bom dia,

Eu andei a pesquisar bastante e descobri que era possivel disparar um processo de python dentro do c#, a minha pergunta é se é possivel fazer isso ao contrario, ou seja disparar uma execução de c# dentro de uma script de python

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, quando diz *"execução de C#"* quer dizer *"um programa escrito em C#"*, correto?
Afinal, C# é só uma linguagem. Um programa executável (que pode ser escrito em outra linguagem qualquer) pode ser executado assim em `python`:

```
import os
os.system("processo.exe")
```

Comment: nesse caso nao é necessário criar executavel do código pois não? e de que maneira eu faço para passar argumentos?

Comment: na própria  chamada, assim `os.system("processo.exe -parametro=valor1"), ou assim tb com variáveis `os.system("processo.exe -parametro={variavel}")`

Comment: ok muito obrigado 
uma ultima pergunta o codigo não precisa de ser compilado pois não? e que como falou em processo.EXE fiquei pensativo de  como fazer para compilar o codigo do c#

Comment: sim precisas compilar o codigo primeiro, para garantir que não tem erros e gerar o executável a partir do C#